# Uib tooltip should appear while mouse over on it

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using uib tooltip, and wanted to show tooltip while mouse over on tooltip. Is there any workaround.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i am using uib-tooltip-template and i have link inside these tooltip title .

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I use in a `component` that controls a popover that stays open while the user hovers it. I know it looks funny, but it's efficient and clear. This is a merging of two solutions I found to different problems using the `ui-bootstrap` popover/tooltip with custom triggers, which I can't find again to give proper credit to right now.

```
app.component('myComponent', {
restrict: 'E',
templateUrl: 'path/to/html/with/popover',
controller: ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    var self = this;
    this.open = false;
    this.hovered = false;

    this.openTooltip = function () {
        this.hovered = true;
        if (!this.open) {
            this.open = true;
        }
    };

    this.keepTooltipOpen = function () {
        this.hovered = true;
    };

    this.closeTooltip = function () {
        this.hovered = false;
        $timeout(function () {
            if (!self.hovered)
                self.open = false;
        }, 500)
    };
}]
});
```

And the HTML itself:

```
<div class="myClass">
<span class="yetAnotherClass"
      ng-attr-uib-popover-template="'my-tooltip.html'"
      popover-placement="top"
      popover-is-open="$ctrl.open"
      ng-mouseenter="$ctrl.openTooltip()"
      ng-mouseleave="$ctrl.closeTooltip()">
    Moo moo
</span>
</div>


<script type="text/ng-template" id="my-tooltip.html">
    <div class="row"
         ng-mouseenter="$ctrl.keepTooltipOpen()"
         ng-mouseleave="$ctrl.closeTooltip()">
        <div>
            bla bla bla
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```